# How do you get / invite beta testers for your iPhone / iPad app?

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store

How do you get / invite beta testers for your iPhone / iPad app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Amazon Mechanical Turk

You might have to pay (maybe some pocket change),i haven't tried it, but a guy from apple said he uses it.